# Multi-panel plot not showing up in flexdashboard on shinyapps.io

Tags: r, plot, shiny, flexdashboard

A four panel plot (created with par() in the usual manner) is not showing up on shinyapps.io. The plot is the last item in one of multiple storyboard pages of plots in a `flexdashboard`. Locally, there is no problem. Any ideas?

The code for the plot is quite simple. Just an `lm()` model being plotted in a 2x2 layout.

````
### Ordinary least squares regression diagnostic plots

```{r}
# OLS diagnostic plots 
par.defaults <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(model_ols)
par(par.defaults)
```
````

**EDIT:**
I now think the issue is not due to the multi-panel plot. It seems like the last plot just isn't displaying.

I tried rearranging the plots in the storyboard, and this particular multi-panel plot displayed fine, while another (regular) plot now reordered as the last item in the storyboard failed to display. I also tried putting the last plot on it's own page (outside of the storyboard) and again, the last plot, and only the last plot, doesn't display.

The shinyapps.io log shows some warnings. Would these have any impact?

> 2016-07-04T14:04:55.891642+00:00 shinyapps[112178]: Warning in normalizePath(path, winslash = winslash, mustWork = mustWork) :
>   2016-07-04T14:04:55.891646+00:00 shinyapps[112178]:   path[1]="figure-html/unnamed-chunk-4-1.mb.png": No such file or directory
>   2016-07-04T14:04:55.894597+00:00 shinyapps[112178]: Warning in normalizePath(path, winslash = winslash, mustWork = mustWork) :
>   2016-07-04T14:04:55.894600+00:00 shinyapps[112178]:   path[1]="figure-html/unnamed-chunk-5-1.mb.png": No such file or directory
>   2016-07-04T14:04:55.897953+00:00 shinyapps[112178]: Warning in normalizePath(path, winslash = winslash, mustWork = mustWork) :
>   2016-07-04T14:04:55.897955+00:00 shinyapps[112178]:   path[1]="figure-html/unnamed-chunk-6-1.mb.png": No such file or directory
>   2016-07-04T14:04:55.901018+00:00 shinyapps[112178]: Warning in normalizePath(path, winslash = winslash, mustWork = mustWork) :
>   2016-07-04T14:04:55.908686+00:00 shinyapps[112178]: Warning in normalizePath(path, winslash = winslash, mustWork = mustWork) :
>   2016-07-04T14:04:55.908688+00:00 shinyapps[112178]:   path[1]="figure-html/unnamed-chunk-4-1.png": No such file or directory
>   2016-07-04T14:04:55.911652+00:00 shinyapps[112178]: Warning in normalizePath(path, winslash = winslash, mustWork = mustWork) :
>   2016-07-04T14:04:55.914592+00:00 shinyapps[112178]: Warning in normalizePath(path, winslash = winslash, mustWork = mustWork) :
>   2016-07-04T14:04:55.914594+00:00 shinyapps[112178]:   path[1]="figure-html/unnamed-chunk-6-1.png": No such file or directory
>   2016-07-04T14:04:55.917612+00:00 shinyapps[112178]: Warning in normalizePath(path, winslash = winslash, mustWork = mustWork) :
>   2016-07-04T14:04:55.917614+00:00 shinyapps[112178]:   path[1]="figure-html/unnamed-chunk-7-1.png": No such file or directory
>   2016-07-04T14:04:56.074425+00:00 shinyapps[112178]: 
>   2016-07-04T14:04:55.911655+00:00 shinyapps[112178]:   path[1]="figure-html/unnamed-chunk-5-1.png": No such file or directory
>   2016-07-04T14:04:55.901020+00:00 shinyapps[112178]:   path[1]="figure-html/unnamed-chunk-7-1.mb.png": No such file or directory

**EDIT2**
I also tried turning off caching in the Rmd file, deleting the app on shinyapps.io, deleting cached files locally, then re-deploying. Still nothing. The last plot just doesn't get displayed.